# Attempting to use Service Fabric PublishProfiles onPrem

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I must be missing something but... When using PowerShell to instantiate a Service Fabric Application I don't see how I can reference a Publish Profile?  To be clear of the ask I want to have multiple instances of an application with the only differences being that Applicaiton Parameter Files.  My understanding is that to use a different application parameter file you should use a different publish profile.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicefabric/vlatest/new-servicefabricapplication

I see the way to use a hashtable to insert the parameters from the PowerShell itself but that is pretty ugly.  I want to refer to one of the Application Parameter files.

I've dug through the other PowerShell commands and do not see a way to pass the application parameter file.  The only place I see that I can pass it is in the SDK version of Publish-NewServiceFabric.ps1.  If I were to use that then I would need to install the SDK onto every cluster?  In my experience I've haven't heard of SDKs going out to servers that have deployed code on them.

https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/135

I must be missing something pretty simple eh?  What am I missing that is right under my nose?

Thanks in advance, 
Greg

Comment: This seems to be a good article for these types of deployments and he says we need to deploy the SDK to the build servers and he then uses the Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1.   http://www.colinsalmcorner.com/post/continuous-deployment-of-service-fabric-apps-using-vsts-or-tfs

Comment: That is pretty much how we have setup our pipeline as well and it works well for us. The Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 is the one where we pass in which publish profile as an argument. The only thing that took some time to get right was all the different versioning when we set it up first time. The article does a good job at describing it though. Deploying the SDK to the build servers is most likely something you cant get around, but having it on the machines in the cluster sounds strange (and I cant see why, but maybe I missunderstood your concern).

Comment: @yoape I hear ya, I think I can force that to work but if you look at the github link above and at the Microsoft PowerShell Documentation they are saying Deploy-FabricApplication is not even really supported to be used.  Its recommended that you use the combination of Copy, Register and then New.  And when doing New you can't pass a publish profile.  So that means that anywhere you run Deploy-FabricApplicaiton from needs to have the SDK installed on it.  I'm wondering if there is a way to do it with out the SDK via normal PS?

Comment: @gperrego Regarding the comment about Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 not being supported, that's not what's stated. I've wrote that I recommend the lower level scripts / CmdLets to do automation as the Deploy-FabricApplication.ps1 is tied to how tooling in VS works.

Comment: @MikkelMørkHegnhøj yes, I'm sorry for the wording, I meant it wasn't supported/recommeneded for use outside of Visual Studio.  So am I missing a cmdlet?  How can I use the lower level scripts and also use a publish profile?  Thanks again.

Comment: Publish profiles are not supported by the PowerShell cmdlets.  As you said, there's the scripts that are shipped as part of the SDK.  That's the only thing that provides support for the publish profile.  If you're in a VSTS scenario, the Service Fabric Deploy task also supports publish profile: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/deploy/service-fabric-deploy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close the loop here the answer to the question is that if you want to deploy to a remote cluster with PublishProfiles you can but you must install the SDK on the box you want to deploy from.

You can not use the "lower level scripts/cmdlets" to deploy to a remote cluster with a publish profile.

If this answer is not clear please let me know and i'll clean up the wording.

Thanks to everyone's time and comments.

Comment: Yes - it's part of Visual Studio and VSTS tooling. However looking at how VS and VTS uses the publish profile, you will be able to replicate this functionality.